# Why is the Atlas Interface's "Obey" choice greyed out?

Tags: no-mans-sky

So I followed the Atlas Path and arrived at the 10th Atlas Interface where I should get my 10th Atlas Stone. The interface offers me the two usual choice "Refuse" and "Obey (Milestone...)" but the second one is greyed out and I can't select it :

[image]

I have empty slots in both my character's and ship's inventories so I don't understand why I can't select the second choice, get the Atlas Stone and the waypoint to what I expect to be the final Atlas interface.

Comment: I'm going to guess when it says you have to be a certain rank or higher to select it that you're probably not a high enough rank.

Comment: OMG, have I played this game 30+ hours without knowing that it's actually an RPG and that you have to grind? I feel so betrayed right now.

Comment: And here I thought it was an MMO all this time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is unrelated to inventory.

You need to be rank Magellan or higher, as it says. To achieve this, you must have accrued a total milestone count of at least 50. The maximum milestone count is 90.

See the Meta title rankings here:
http://nomanssky.wikia.com/wiki/Journey_milestones

Comment: Your link says that Magellan is at 50 not 55.

Comment: Edited to fix the number, thanks for catching that.